# Stretch or scroll parent flex box

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS that I'm trying to get to either stretch or scroll the parent flex box without a static width. I can't seem to get either result.

No matter how many `box` classes I add, it doesn't make the flex box stretch or scrollable. I want to be able to have a `box` of 300 width even if it means to be able to scroll but all it does is make `box` smaller and doesn't respect the width of it.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/r4j778xg/2/

```
<div class="flex">
<div class="box">stuff</div>
<div class="box">stuff</div>
<div class="box">stuff</div>
...many more
</div>

.flex
{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.box
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

Comment: placing width:100% on your flex element will make it 100% of body (in your case)

Comment: Right, which is why I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve a `width: 9999px` solution ;)

Comment: some days back I answered a question giving a solution to a problem setting `{width:500%; display: flex}` to parent element. if you want [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702110/css-horizontal-scroll-tricks/27703546#27703546) (there's also a snippet)

Comment: I suspect that you've completely misunderstood what Flexbox is for. The intention - as the name suggests - is to adapt the width/height (=flex) of an element w/i a flex container, so that these elements will fill out the space in the column/row. The ratio can be controlled by `flex: <N>` or be fixed with `width/height`. See [this guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) So, a scollable flexbox sounds like an [oxymoron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron) to me.

Comment: @try-catch-finally Nice catch ;D However it does help with vertically and horizontally centering content inside the scrollable flexbox. Which would be a pain otherwise (specially the vertical centering part).

Comment: Your question was [X/Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and not precise enough. :) If I understand your comment correctly you'd like to center the row of `.box`es vertically, further you want the (variable?) number of `.box`es to center horizontally if there's enough space and make the wrapping container scroll if there's not enough space?

Comment: @try-catch-finally That was an interesting read. But no, I was speaking in general and not of this example in particular.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I agree that flexboxes are originally meant for something else.... but vertical centering feature is some good stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with, with my thinking 100% its means fill parent container which is window width so you cant get wider than that

```
.flex{
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/Luzvps05/)

Plus if you want keep this `position: relative;` to keep height value so next element show after this one you can wrap it like this

[JFSIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/gnu5kva8/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Beautiful. :D

Comment: Actually, is the last example supposed to be scrollable? -- Never mind, changed the `overflow` to `scroll`. Simply awesome, you went above and beyond. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are setting a *relative* `width:100%` to you `flex` div, and its parent doesn't even have a fixed width so *the problem is 100% of what?*, so when you make a fixed width to your parent div (body for example) the problem will be solved:

```
body{
  width:1096px;
  height:960px;
}
```

And Give your flex div a `display: inline;` or `display: table;`, because `display: flex;` will force the div to be a block-level flex container.

This is a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4j778xg/8/)**.

I think that should do it.

Comment: Even so it doesn't keep the width of 300px for class `box`. The boxes are 137 pixels in that example

Comment: @Tek: Well pointed out I missed that, It's fixed by giving the flex div a `display: inline;` or `display: table;`, I will EDIT my answer.