# CSS Horizontal Scroll tricks

Tags: html, css

So here is my content:

```
<div class="items_viewed" id="block1">
    <div class="item_wrapped">
        <div id="item1" class="item">item 1</div>
        <div id="item2" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item3" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item4" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item5" class="item">item 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="items_viewed" id="block2">
    <div class="item_wrapped">
        <div id="item1" class="item">item 1</div>
        <div id="item2" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item3" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item4" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item5" class="item">item 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as simple as it can get:

```
.items_viewed {
    width:100%; 
    height:410px; 
    overflow:auto;
}
.item_wrapped {
    width:990px;
}
.item {
    height:380px; 
    width:148px; 
    background:#CCCCCC; 
    float:left; 
    margin:4px;
}
```

I need the first `block1` to start with `item1` as the first viewable item and `block2` to show `item5` as the first viewable item.

Thus when the user scrolls the page, he swipes right to left for `block1` and left to right for `block2`.

`direction:ltr` doesn't seem to be helping. And I don't want to use Javascript since it will increase the load time.

Please advise

> Edit:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/8of8j0d9/ Just for reference

Comment: You have duplicated your id's. element ID's are meant to be unique, should should never repeat themselves, as this may/will lead to bugs in some/most browsers. Please ensure you NEVER repeat element ID's to avoid this.

Comment: This is just the dummy code. All the ids are auto generated through PHP and unique in the final output

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javascript, and need to change the order or the tags in your page, I guess you should change you HTML code, or maybe output it with PHP to be able to re-order the tags as you like ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to render them in reversed order or play a little bit with css, something like:

```
<div class="items_viewed" id="block2">
    <div class="item_wrapped right">

.item_wrapped.right div { float: right; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the scenario you're describing could be nicely inplemented with **flexboxes,**
for reference take a look at [this](http://ss-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ,

this is how I would integrate it:

```css
.items_viewed{height:410px; overflow-y:auto; }
.item_wrapped{display:flex; width:500%;}
#block1{overflow-x: scroll;direction:ltr;flex-direction:row-reverse;}
#block2{overflow-x: scroll;direction:rtl;flex-direction:row-reverse;}
.item{height:380px; width:100%; background:#CCCCCC; float:left; margin:4px;}
```

```html
<div class="items_viewed" id="block1">
    <div class="item_wrapped top">
        <div id="item1" class="item">item 1</div>
        <div id="item2" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item3" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item4" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item5" class="item">item 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="items_viewed" id="block2">
    <div class="item_wrapped bottom">
        <div id="item1" class="item">item 1</div>
        <div id="item2" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item3" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item4" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item5" class="item">item 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```